# Is it possible to know what medium is used for sharing in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to capture the selected medium for sharing. I have an iOS app and there's a share button which shares a predefined template. When a user clicks on the share button, he is presented with the apps available that can used to share that, and if user selects Facebook or WhatsApp or Skype, they are redirected to the native apps of the medium they selected. Now I want to know what they selected.

Comment: What are you using for this sharing? `UIActivityViewController`? Have you looked at the docs for its completion handler?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I'm going to use `UIActivityViewController `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIActivityViewController's `completionWithItemsHandler` to check which activitytype user has selected and whether they completed the activity or cancelled it:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[ "Hello"], applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in

  //check completed
  if completed{
    //check activity type using activity type
    if activityType!==UIActivityTypePostToFacebook{
      //Facebook 
    }
   and so on 
  }
}
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for sharing in objective C with UIActivityViewController

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
   NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In Swift with UIActivityViewController:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.codingexplorer.com/") {
    let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    //New Excluded Activities Code
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
    //

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

if you want to perticular sharing on facebook You can use SLComposeViewController in objective C

```
 if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    fbSLComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbSLComposeViewController addImage:someImage];
    [fbSLComposeViewController setInitialText:@"Some Text"];
    [self presentViewController:fbSLComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    fbSLComposeViewController.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch(result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"facebook: CANCELLED");
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"facebook: SHARED");
                break;
        }
    };
}
else {
    UIAlertView *fbError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Unavailable" message:@"Sorry, we're unable to find a Facebook account on your device.\nPlease setup an account in your devices settings and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [fbError show];
}
```

SLComposeViewController in Swift

```
 @IBAction func facebookButtonPushed(sender: UIButton) {
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
    var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    facebookSheet.setInitialText("Share on Facebook")
    self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Please read the question first, I know how to share, but wanted to get the medium for share selected by the user while sharing, so I can keep track of what medium is being used for most of the sharing.